# How to compute the number of gradient evaluations in Jax.Scipy.minimize.optimize?

Tags: jax

I wish to obtain the total number of gradient evaluations during optimization using jax.scipy.optimize.minimize. How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find this in the `njev` (number of Jacobian evaluations) attribute of the output of `minimize`. For example:

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax.scipy.optimize import minimize

def f(x):
  return jnp.sum(x ** 2)

out = minimize(f, jnp.array([1., 2.]), method="BFGS")
print(out.njev)
```

```
3
```

You can find a list of the information available in the optimization output in the documentation for [`OptimizeResults`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.scipy.optimize.OptimizeResults.html).